# How to implement interfaces in MyHDL

Tags: myhdl

In VHDL, I often use records to group related signals into something that can be passed around as a single object, e.g. in a port map. What's the MyHDL way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfaces are available in the 0.9-dev and 
are straightforward.  If you have an object 
(class) with Signals in it it will be name
extended in conversion.

It is explained in the MEP 
http://www.myhdl.org/doku.php/meps:mep-107

More examples available here (I realize it 
is not well documented - yet):

https://bitbucket.org/cfelton/minnesota

Also, a small example available here:

http://www.edaplayground.com/s/130/941

Comment: Fabulous. Let's get rid of these ugly signal lists ;-)

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder :)  List of Signals is very useful for modeling memory (and convertible).